# Daisy-chainable DisplayPort Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, external-display, displayport, daisychaining

I am the proud new owner of a MacBook Pro with a mini-DisplayPort. My desk setup used to allow me to position the screen of my old MacBook beside an external monitor, essentially allowing dual-head. It was also advantageous that my old MBP and my external monitor had the same resolution, `1440x900`.

Now, I'm searching for a set of two monitors that I can use a [HengeDock](http://www.hengedocks.com/) with. Unfortunately, the MacBook Pro suffers from having only one mini-DisplayPort.

Looking up the spec for DisplayPort 1.2 (which the MBP supports), DisplayPort daisy chaining is supported. What I'm looking for is a monitor that has **two** DisplayPorts so I can daisy chain two monitors off the single mini-DisplayPort.

What I **don't** want is a USB-based video solution. I need full acceleration on both monitors; an external video card won't cut it. I hope I don't have to wait a few years for these monitors to come out.

TL;DR: I need two monitors with two DisplayPorts each that I can daisy-chain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dell now offers (at least) two monitors with DisplayPort 1.2 ports for daisy-chaining:

[Dell U2713H 27" Monitor](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=soho&cs=ussoho1&sku=225-4148&~ck=dellSearch&baynote_bnrank=0&baynote_irrank=2)

[Dell UltraSharp u2913WM 29" Ultra-wide monitor](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=soho&cs=ussoho1&sku=225-4201&~ck=dellSearch&baynote_bnrank=0&baynote_irrank=3)

I cannot, however, confirm that they work with the MacBook Pros. If/when these ports start showing up on their lower-end monitors I might take the plunge.

Comment: I only have one response: YAY!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think monitor makers have DP1.2 yet.  But, you're in luck, because there are DP1.2 MST hubs.  It's like a usb hub, but for display port instead.  You plug one display port cable into the DP1.2 MST hub, and then you have 4 different display port cables that come out of the hub and into your various monitors.  The advantage of using a DP1.2 MST hub is that it plugs right into old-school DP1.0 monitors.

By the way, are you sure your MacBook Pro has DP1.2?  AMD just started making DP1.2 radeon cards, and I think nVidia also just began -- it's unlikely Apple picked up these parts so quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You know, you could always crosspost this answer to my [question with bounty](http://superuser.com/questions/230744/looking-for-a-real-displayport-hub-splitter) so I can properly reward you for it. This answer is more relevant to that question anyways.

Answer (score 4):

For a while you are able to list all DP 1.2 MST capable devices on [displayport.org](http://www.displayport.org/products-database/). Just select the **DP Displays Multi-Stream** option.