# Looking for a real DisplayPort hub/splitter

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dvi, displayport, splitter

In my search for a new display, I came across the [Dell Multi-Monitor Hub MMH11](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&orig_s=corp&sku=330-9118&s=bsd), which seemed to be an alternative to my [search for daisy-chainable DisplayPort displays](https://superuser.com/questions/228589).

However, before I cave and spend $179 on this device, I am wondering if this will be similar to other splitting devices where it appears to the computer as one big monitor and the device does the splitting (which I **don't** want). Or, does this use the packet-based nature of DisplayPort to present two/three separate displays to the computer?

Also, would this device work on my MacBook Pro? (I know the Dell site says it's for Windows, but it also says that no driver installation is required. I'd assume since the MBP supports DP 1.2 it would work, but it's better to ask). Thanks!

**Edit:** I've checked out the similar-looking [Cirago DisplayPort splitter](http://cirago.com/wordpress/products/displayadapters/hdx3dp01/), but I have extreme doubts as to whether or not it's a genuine displayport splitter, or just another monitor-conglomerate. Their DVI solution looks identical to Dell's, which I'm pretty sure won't do what I want. I also don't want to order this DisplayPort *"hub"* and find that it doesn't do what I want it to.

Comment: No DP 1.2 hubs yet...

Comment: @iconiK Anything to back that up? While a DisplayPort hub would be nice, I'm trying to ascertain whether or not this will do the same thing.

Comment: @squircle, look at the specs; says no where it is DP 1.2. Besides, all current DP hubs merge all monitors into a single big monitor.

Comment: I just got off a chat with a Dell rep and was told that the Dell Multi-monitor hub (MMH11) was not compatible with macs (not sure whether they know that it does not work or they just don't know and reply conservatively). Sucks though, I was considering it too!

Comment: @wrocks I'm pretty sure it would be Mac-compatible, but the software wouldn't be (other identical devices without the Dell branding are compatible with any OS).

Comment: Anyone found any updates on this?

Comment: FYI the Cirago is definitely a monitor aggregation hub, and reports a single monitor to the host machine.

Comment: It's 2013. Any updates on this?

Comment: @BrianTheLion Yep, there certainly is. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, it looks like we have a **real** DisplayPort MST (multi-stream transport) hub: 
[image: Club3D MST hub]

See [Club3D's product page](http://www.club-3d.com/index.php/products/reader.en/product/mst-hub-1-3.html) for more info. It's pretty cheap too, only $120 CAD. Unfortunately for me, it requires DisplayPort 1.2 support (or AMD EyeFinity) which my MacBook Pro doesn't have, and it turns out that OS X doesn't support MST at all, but [Windows does on Apple hardware](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23493980#23493980).

Comment: Mac OS X does support MST, here is a list of Macs with the feature and MST displays that are officially supported: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202856. However OS X only supports MST for single displays - it can't do MST across multiple displays (which is probably what Club3D's hardware requires).

Answer (score 3):

The only chipset I'm aware that can do this yet is the IDT VMM1400, yet I'm not aware of any devices that use it. This should help find what you're looking for!

Oh, and the Cirago DisplayPort splitter has a description that seems certain to only provide a single display.

Comment: It turns out that the Cirago, Startech, and Dell are all based on the previous revision of the IDT chipset which did not support a true switching / daisy-chain mode.  This new chipset, supporting independent displays, has only been available since October. I recommend contacting IDT, if anyone is building such a device with their chip, they'll know. Most likely, you'll have to wait another 1-6 months.

Comment: @ewin But their description says *" The IDT VMM1400 multi-monitor controller is compliant with the VESA DisplayPort™ v1.1a and HDMI™ v1.3, and uses one DisplayPort input port and four HDMI or DVI output ports."* Weren't daisy-chaining/DisplayPort hubs added in VESA's DisplayPort 1.2 spec?

Comment: True, it does say compliant with DisplayPort v1.1a, but their press release also says, "The IDT VMM1400 is configurable to operate in hub or daisy chain mode. In hub mode, the VMM1400 supports four HDMI or DVI outputs that can display on up to four monitors. In daisy chain mode, the ViewXpand device supports a connection to downstream devices (for example, another VMM1400) to form the daisy chain of monitors compatible with the current DisplayPort standard"

Comment: Although possible, I doubt they would claim that it supports daisy-chain unless the chipset can actually do it. It is possible that they failed to advertise it as a v1.2 device. Either way, there seems to be no devices actually built on this chip. It seems, too, that the devices built on the old chip were also built by IDT, Dell and Cirago simply rebranded the device (or built it to a reference design)

Comment: @ewindisch It must have been either mis-labeled, or just doing the *one-huge-display* thing. *"Other improvements ]in DisplayPort 1.2] include multiple independent video streams (daisy-chain connection with multiple monitors)..." So unless it's DP 1.2, I guess it won't cut it. Thanks anyways for the suggestion!

Comment: @ewindisch And on the product page for that chip, they link to the Dell adapter and the Cirago adapter, so I guess it won't do what I need it to.

Comment: I agree, it *must* be DP1.2 to do the daisy-chain. The press release explicitly says it does daisy-chain, despite claiming being v1.1a. It is worth contacting IDT for clarification.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm quite sure that the Dell and Cirago adapter are based on their VMM1300 chipset.

Answer (score 1):

The [UltraAV® Mini DisplayPort 1.2 MST Multi-Display Hub](http://www.accellcables.com/K088B-003B.html) might suit. (130 USD.)

Advantage: it's directly used on mini displayport, adapters from DP to mDP are only needed for the screens.

NB: The splitter costs more than 200 € whereas the MST hub costs far less.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the spec doc for this (warning, PDF link):

> http://i.dell.com/images/global/products/monitors/mmh11.pdf

It supports display splitting and cloning, so it should act like any multi-monitor setup. As for OS X support, I'm not sure.

Edit: I just found another adapter to do the same thing:

The matrox DualHead2Go DP Edition does this, but instead of DP -> 3xDVI it does DP->2xDP and it OS X compatible and supports output resolution of 2 x 1920 x 1200 with the help of USB power, but according to the two reviews, it says you have to have two of the same monitors for it work properly on OS X at least.

> http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815106021

Edit: matrox has a compatibility listing of their products here for Apple products:

> http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/mac/choice/

Comment: I just sent Matrox an email as to whether each display connected to the Dual/TripleHead2Go shows up as a separate display to the system, and I hope to hear from them soon. The thing I'm worried about with the Dell device is whether or not the configuration is managed through software through the USB connection. If it is, and there's no software for Mac, I'm out of luck. I'd prefer to buy the Dell solution because it's cheaper, but if I'm not sure it's going to work, I'd rather buy the Matrox (assuming it does what I want it to do). I'll let you know what happens here.

Comment: I have confirmed [here](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Matrox-DualHead2Go-DP-DisplayPort-Edition.32029.0.html) that the Dual/TripleHead2Go doesn't allow independent operation of the monitors; they appear as one big display. Thanks for the suggestion, though. I'm going to try to find out more about the Dell device.

Comment: The Dell unit is made by Startech: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GlOy60-fpc&feature=related

Comment: I can confirm that the MMH11 does not support independent monitor mode. It appears as a single big monitor in Windows, making it not fit for purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The Atlona AT-MDP12 Mini Display Port Splitter appears to be a multi-port Mini Displayport Hub that really does split up the signals to provide individual self-contained screens instead of a single screen that spans monitors.

Found it here:
[TigerDirect.ca](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=6823735&CatId=466)

More Info:
[Altona Website](http://www.atlona.com/ATLONA-1x2-MINI-DISPLAYPORT-SPLITTER.html)

This may be a godsend to me in particular, as I am running a pair of HP 4:3 ratio monitors pumping out 1600×1200 resolution apiece, off of the Belkin dual-head 4-port KVM. Since this KVM is VGA-only, I can attach two Mini Displayport to VGA adapters to this unit, and connect them to the KVM. Presto, dual monitors being run from a Macbook Pro in a HengeDock.

**Edited to add:** I just had a closer look at the documentation and they are NOT CLEAR if this is a traditional splitter (like a VGA splitter, which just duplicates a screen) or if it is a thunderbolt-style splitter (which would allow the graphics core on a MacBook Pro to see each DisplayPort port as a separate connection, and to pump different images to each monitor). I have emailed them to ask for a clarification, and will do my best to update this post if I receive a reply.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much. I eagerly await your reply. :)

Comment: Any word from the manufacturer?

Comment: Nope, not a bloody word. I will try to pester them a little bit more. Anyone want to help?

Answer (score 0):

Found one. [Belkin is releasing a Thunderbolt Hub](http://www.macgasm.net/2012/01/09/belkin-announces-thunderbolt-hub/) in 2012, with TWO downstream Thunderbolt ports.

Only problem: it’s slated to be $299 retail. Ouch.

Comment: Thunderbolt `!=` DisplayPort, unfortunately.