# Is it possible to connect 2 dvi monitors to 1 display port

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, dvi, displayport, optimus

I have a lenovo t530 laptop with nvidia optimus card and a single display port on it.

I want to connect 2 dvi monitors to it, the documenation says this is possible with the docking station which has 2 dvi connectors on it. Is there anyway to connect them to the laptops display port itself without buying a docking station? like a display port splitter cable to dvi or something?

Answer (score 0):

There are display port splitters ([Startech](http://www.startech.com/AV/Splitters/DisplayPort) among others make them). There is one specifically for [dual DVI](http://www.startech.com/AV/Splitters/DisplayPort/DisplayPort-to-Dual-DVI-Multi-Monitor-Adapter-Male-to-Female-DP-to-2x-DVI-3840x1200~SP122DP2DVI). This would allow you to expand or clone your desktop (but not extend I believe). There are some cheaper ones but you probably get what you pay for.

The advantage to a docking station is that other cables (like ethernet, keyboard/mouse) can be plugged in and left connected.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are [no verified DisplayPort Hubs](https://superuser.com/questions/230744/looking-for-a-real-displayport-hub-splitter) which will function as two DVI ports. You can get a splitter which will merge the two displays into one large display, however.

The docking stations probably uses additional outputs from the graphics card that are not exposed on the laptop itself.