# How do I know if I will be able to daisy-chain monitors? (connect two monitors to 1 DisplayPort)

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport

I am planning to use [Surface Pro 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Surface_Pro_2) with a dock station as my main computer and I would like to connect two external monitors to it, but [the dock station](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/hardware-and-drivers/docking-station) only contains a single DisplayPort socket. However, I see that [DisplayPort 1.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#1.2) specification, approved in 2009, allows for daisy-chaining monitors through its *Multi-Stream Transport* feature.

How do I tell if I will be able to use two monitors in daisy-chain mode with my computer?

Comment: I have a Surface Pro 2 and I have used it with two Dell U2515H monitors via the Display Port. The monitors were 2560 x 1440 and it could drive them fine, no dock was used though.

Answer (score 12):

Surface Pro 2 [ships](http://www.theverge.com/2014/1/2/5266988/surface-pro-2-intel-i5-processor-updated-specifications) with either [i5-4200U](http://ark.intel.com/products/75459/) or [i5-4300U](http://ark.intel.com/products/76308/) CPU, both [*Haswell* chips with HD Graphics 4400 GPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i5_microprocessors#.22Haswell-ULT.22_.28SiP.2C_dual-core.2C_22_nm.29). [According to Intel](https://communities.intel.com/thread/46389), these chips have 4<sup>th</sup> generation graphics ([HD Graphics 4200 and up is 4<sup>th</sup>, 4000 and 2500 is 3<sup>rd</sup>](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics)) and thus support DisplayPort 1.2.

Apart from graphics adapter support, you will need compatible monitors. These monitors should be DisplayPort 1.2 compatible and feature two DisplayPorts (for input and output). According to [this page](http://www.displayport.org/products-database/?products_category%5B%5D=pc-digital-displays-multi-stream) from DisplayPort.org (click 'DP Displays Multi-Stream' then 'Search') there are currently seven such models:

- [Lenovo LT2934z](http://mobilesupport.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/PD029134)
- [Asus PA279Q](http://www.asus.com/News/HrDwMcYKen95l8ov)
- [Dell U2413](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=320-9567&baynote_bnrank=0&baynote_irrank=0&~ck=baynoteSearch)
- [Dell U2414H](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&cs=19&sku=860-BBCG&baynote_bnrank=0&baynote_irrank=0&~ck=baynoteSearch)
- [Dell U2713H](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=225-4148&baynote_bnrank=0&baynote_irrank=0&~ck=baynoteSearch)
- [Dell U2913WM](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&sku=225-4201&baynote_bnrank=0&baynote_irrank=0&~ck=baynoteSearch&redirect=1)
- [Dell U3014](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=225-4429&baynote_bnrank=0&baynote_irrank=0&~ck=baynoteSearch)

Or, you could use DisplayPort 1.2 MST hub [like this one](http://smile.amazon.com/EVGA-Compliant-Multi-Stream-Displayport-200-DP-1301-L1/dp/B00HK8V5KE/): not quite daisy-chain, but a solution to connect up to 3 DisplayPort monitors to a single DP 1.2 MST output. The monitors can be regular old-school DP 1.0, [according to this answer](https://superuser.com/a/234677/52027).

Comment: is it possible to use a legacy non-DP monitor with such a hub?

Comment: @prusswan, supposedly, yes, see what the last sentence says.

Comment: The list is out of date. There are monitors, like the [Dell U2415M](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-u2415/pd) that support DP 1.2 but aren't listed on that product page.

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury Could you please edit the answer?

Comment: So if a monitor only has one display port on the back (not two. Only one display port which I'm assuming is a 'DP in'), this means it can't daisy chain without having something like a DP hub? This one display port cant be used as a 'DP out' if I use another port like VGA to deliver the video signal?