# Dell XPS 13 with 2 monitors daisychain?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, dell-xps, daisychaining, mst

I'm going to buy a Dell XPS 13 (the i5 model without touchscreen and with 256gb ssd) and i'm also going to buy a Dell Ultrasharp monitor U2515H. But in the future i really want to buy a second monitor (the same), but is it possible (will it work?!) to connect the laptop to one monitor, and connect the second monitor with daisychain?

(Sorry for my bad english)

Thanks, Carlijn.

Example of what i mean below:
[image]

Comment: Please provide the exact model number of your notebook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know if I will be able to daisy-chain monitors? (connect two monitors to 1 DisplayPort)](http://superuser.com/questions/760889/how-do-i-know-if-i-will-be-able-to-daisy-chain-monitors-connect-two-monitors-t)

Answer (score -1):

I would guess that any form of Daisychain would cause the screens to be clones of each other and not both usable.

You have two options you can try to use two monitors via two separate outputs on the Laptop (e.g. one from VGA and one from HDMI). This works on some graphics cards and not others again you can end up with cloned screens instead of extended.

Worse case scenario you can buy a USB to VGA adaptor for the second monitor which will allow you to use both screens... something similar to below:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-Multi-Monitor-External-Adapter/dp/B002FJQXXC

Comment: that isn't how DP 1.2 daisy chaining works.

Comment: very interesting I knew nothing about daisy chaining via DP before, I've got a dell laptop and monitor as well, will have to reconsider getting a 2nd monitor...

Comment: The specific DP 1.2 feature isn't actually called daisy chaining, I can't recall the feature name but did research for a comment I made just this week on an Haswell capability with an Apple hardware, but in the end what is descriped is daisy chaining.

Comment: Yeah I just had a read up on it, its about time that a display port done something clever as DVI was a bit of a let down :)