# Is daisy-chaining displayports in decline?

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport, daisychaining

I am looking for a solution to connect a large computer monitor and a larger UHD TV to a not-yet-purchased new computer.  I could get one with a chipset or video card with enough video connectors for my solution, or I could consider daisy-chaining.  In [this 2014 answer](https://superuser.com/a/760890/133195), which suggests to use the displayport.org website to find monitors supporting daisy-chaining with DisplayPort, 7 monitors are listed supporting DisplayPort Multi-Stream.  But when I search today on [displayport.org](https://www.displayport.org/product-category/monitors-tvs/?ps&pcat[0]=pc-digital-displays-multi-stream), it lists only 2 results.  Is the technique of daisy-chaining DisplayPort monitors in decline, or is the listing on displayport.org possibly incomplete?

Comment: Why do you assume that displayport.org contains every such monitor in the world?

Comment: Hmm. This question seem to be opinion based and/or hardware recommendation  and might go down better with some rewording...

Comment: @DavidPostill In fact, the question linked by the OP is nicely worded, but the answer is still of the kind that recommends specific hardware and needs constant updating. I can see the usefulness of this question (many connecting technologies have been made obsolete and it'd be good to know before purchase), but perhaps this is something better asked on [chat]?

Comment: ^^^^^ Agreed :)

Comment: @harrymc Because the linked question suggests it.