# How can I daisy chain a Surface Pro 2 to multiple monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, microsoft-surface, daisychaining

I am considering a Surface Pro 2, and have read on [this Microsoft site](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-gb/support/music-photos-and-video/connect-surface-pro-to-a-tv-display-or-projector) that:

> If you have the latest Windows updates, you can daisy-chain multiple monitors from your Surface Pro 2.

They don't seem to elaborate on this.

This would be awesome if true, but how exactly does this work? Could I do this with bog standard 1080p HDMI monitiors?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Could I do this with bog standard 1080p HDMI monitiors?

No, but you should be able to do that with bog standard 1080p [display port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) monitors.

From [the Microsoft website which you linked you](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-gb/support/music-photos-and-video/connect-surface-pro-to-a-tv-display-or-projector):
HDTV: If your TV has an HDMI port, you’ll need a HDMI cable and a Mini **DisplayPort** to HD AV adapter or an HDMI to Mini DisplayPort cable (sold separately).

I read `HDMI to Mini DisplayPort cable` as:

- From display port to HDMI
- And "cable" as "something with two plugs on it. One DP, one HDMI. The actual part between does not need to be a cable but can be active electronics instead".

Combine that with the known ability of display port monitors to daisy-chain and you have your answer.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that not ever cable is created equal.  He will need a cable that supports DisplayPort 1.2 which supports daisy chaining.

Comment: Related: [Daisy-chainable DisplayPort Monitors](http://superuser.com/questions/228589/daisy-chainable-displayport-monitors?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Since asking this question I have discovered the USB3 pluggable, which can do this well. There is a good video on this [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ncaCRHJvR).